# Cannot Update- Insufficient Space- Extend Folder to External HDD?

Tags: partitioning, disk-usage

I have my computer on a dual-boot linux/winXP with a partitioned hard drive for each. Recently my linux ran out of memory and cannot update. I tried sudo apt-get clean and that worked for a while but not any more. I tried using the windows program to change the partitions up but the linux one was locked for some reason. I read something about using a live cd to try and repartition it but I really don't want to do that. I have an external HDD and wanted to know if I could somehow just extend the folder somehow or something? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending root partition to an external drive is not a good idea as this drive may not be ready at boot or become inaccessible in other ways (e.g. by unplugging).

If you run out of disk space in addition to

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

you can free space by **[removing old kernel images](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1587462)**.

**Take care not to remove your present kernel**

Comment: Thanks! I probably have like 20 kernels, but have never spent the time to figure out how to get rid of them...